# Spring JPA 1 Entity handles 2 tables and i have 2 persist methods

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

**It looks similar with many questions but i will explain you the difference here.**

I have 10 tables , each of the 10 tables has one history table , so totally 20 tables .

`Normal Table` and `History Table` have exactly the same columns .

Data comes inside the `Normal Table` , getting processed and then passed into `History Table` of that specific table .

Column names are just random , they have like 20 columns ( *check the code i added below* )

```
Normal Table            

╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  Name        ║ Etc  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 1234 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║ 1234 ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║ 1234 ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║ 1234 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝ 

History of Normal Table

╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  Name        ║ Etc  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 3456 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║ 3456 ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║ 3456 ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║ 3456 ║

║... ║ ............ ║  ... ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

---

I used to have `20 entities` for 20 tables , until i found that i can do the below (use `@SecondaryTable`) annotation and have `10 entities` :

```
@Entity(name = "sepa_card_customers_mandate")
@Table
@SecondaryTable(name = "sepa_card_customers_mandate_history")
public class CardCustomerMandate extends Mandate {

    @Column(name = "RECEIPT_NUMBER")
    private String receiptNumber;

    @Column(name = "GAMES")
    private String games;

    public CardCustomerMandate() {
    }

    public CardCustomerMandate(final Mandate mandate, final String receiptNumber, final String games) {
        super(mandate);
        this.receiptNumber = receiptNumber;
        this.games = games;
    }

    public String getReceiptNumber() {
        return receiptNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptNumber(final String receiptNumber) {
        this.receiptNumber = receiptNumber;
    }

    public String getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(final String games) {
        this.games = games;
    }
}
```

---

All good until here . The problem comes , when i use (`persist(Instance T)` build in JPA method it saves the record on `sepa_card_customers_mandate`.

But then i also want to save the entity on history table so i have created the below , *i am just doing a 
native query to save the object into the history* :

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO sepa_subscription_credit_mandate_history " +
    " (PLAYER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, IBAN, BIC, BALANCE, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, DRAW_NUMBER, WINNING_DATE, GAMES, BIT8_UNIQUE_ID, SEPA_UNIQUE_ID, CREATED_AT) " +
    " VALUES(:#{#m.getPlayerId()}, :#{#m.getFirstName()}, :#{#m.getLastName()}, :#{#m.getIban()}, :#{#m.getBic()}, :#{#m.getBalance()}, " +
    " :#{#m.getSubscriptionID()}, :#{#m.getDrawNumber()}, :#{#m.getWinningDate()}, :#{#m.getGames()}, :#{#m.getBit8UniqueId()}, " +
    " :#{#m.getSepaUniqueId()}, :#{#m.getCreatedAt()})", nativeQuery = true)
void saveHistory(@Param("m") SubscriptionCreditMandate m);
```

---

My question is :

**Is there a better way that using native query ?**

Comment: I am not sure about your general approach. The history table appears to have a number of records per user so is `@SecondaryTable` really what you want. Looks more like a `OneToMany` relationship. If you are using Hibernate see also Envers which will maintain audit history for you.

Comment: @AlanHay Ouh just edited the question so it doesn't seem like that any more, they are unrelated completely, same user never appears again, my mistake on the example :)

Comment: Why not use triggers on main table to put data into history table?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj So i have to write  10 triggers for 10 tables ?